# Cómo actualizar solo un específico valor en Firebase Database en Web

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-messaging, firebase-auth

**Quiero cambiar el valor de una propiedad con un update/set
Puedo editarlo con un ngModel pero no actualizar el dato específico. Borra todos(ramas de de users(padre root))**

users(list) -> ACJSLDKJ234NLCJS-L5 -> name: value

```
**service**

  edit(name) {
    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('name').push().key;
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + newPostKey).set({name: name})
  }

**component**

  formEdit() {
    this.authService.edit(this.editItem);
  }

  edit(item) {
    this.editItem = item;
  }


**html**

<form (ngSubmit)="formEdit()">
   <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="editItem.name"></ion-input>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-button block color="primary" type="submit">edit</ion-button>
</form>
```

Comment: Tienes que añadir merge: true, como en ejemplo adjunto.
firebase.database().ref('users/' + newPostKey).set({name: name}, {merge: true}),
esto provoca si un campo no existe se añade y si existe se actualiza

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás construyendo mal la sentencia en la que pides una nueva `key` con `push`. Prueba algo así porfa:

```
const newUser = firebase.database().ref("users").push();
const key = newUser.key;
firebase.database().ref('users/' + key).set({name: name})
```

Si quisieras utilizar `update` en lugar de `set` para añadir más propiedades al objeto, [puedes chequear si existe esa referencia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists) y usar `set` o `update` dependiendo.

Saludos.